# How does upsampling in Fully Connected Convolutional network work?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I read several posts / articles and have some doubts on the mechanism of upsampling after the CNN downsampling.

I took the 1st answer from this question:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-fully-convolutional-networks-upsample-their-coarse-output

I understood that similar to normal convolution operation, the "upsampling" also uses kernels which need to be trained.

Question1: if the "spatial information" is already lost during the first stages of CNN, how can it be re-constructed in anyway ?

Question2: Why >"Upsampling from a small (coarse) featuremap deep in the network has good semantic information but bad resolution. Upsampling from a larger feature map closer to the input, will produce better detail but worse semantic information" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Question #1**

Upsampling doesn't (and cannot) reconstruct any lost information. Its role is to bring back the resolution to the resolution of previous layer.

Theoretically, we can eliminate the down/up sampling layers altogether. However to reduce the number of computations, we can downsample the input before a layers and then upsample its output.

Therefore, the sole purpose of down/up sampling layers is to reduce computations in each layer, while keeping the dimension of input/output as before.

You might argue the down-sampling might cause information loss. That is always a possibility but remember the role of CNN is essentially extracting "useful" information from the input and reducing it into a smaller dimension.

**Question #2**

As we go from the input layer in CNN to the output layer, the dimension of data generally decreases while the semantic and extracted information hopefully increases.

Suppose we have the a CNN for image classification. In such CNN, the early layers usually extract the basic shapes and edges in the image. The next layers detect more complex concepts like corners, circles. You can imagine the very last layers might have nodes that detect very complex features (like presence of a person in the image).

So up-sampling from a large feature map close to the input produces better detail but has lower semantic information compared to the last layers. In retrospect, the last layers generally have lower dimension hence their *resolution* is worse compared to the early layers.

Comment: Thank you Isaac. For the #1 question, I read somewhere on the internet that while more complex features are extracted during the convolution process (as dimension reduces and feature vector increases), the "spatial information" of certain feature is lost so the result produced by CNN is insensitive to the deformation or relocation. 
If so, how could the "up-sampling" process be trained to classify the features at PIXEL level ?

Comment: @captainst: That's right. In computer vision, CNNs are usually invariant to position, orientation, and scale of the objects. But note that this is because we train them to be invariant. e.g. we label all images with a car as `car`, no matter where the car is located in the image. If we had classes based on the spatial information, e.g. classes `car on the left` and `car on the right`, CNN learns to preserve the horizontal spatial information as a feature for a car to be able to classify it into one of these two classes. I didn't get the last part of your question. would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: Thank you again. I think I'm getting close to your answer. Let me try to explain my doubt in another way: If we divide the Fully Connected Convolution Network into 2 parts: The downsampling part and the upsampling part. If I understood correctly, the downsampling part tries to extract high-level features while "ignoring" the spatial information to make the model invariant to position shift. So, it seems obvious that the upsampling part has to somehow retrieve the spatial information in order to make segmentation at pixel level. (otherwise how could the model classify each pixel ?)

Comment: I think that I am getting your point by your example of "car on the left and car on the right". Actually when using a normal CNN (like inception model) to classify an image, during the training, the model ignores **on purpose** the spatial information by tuning the weights properly. However, if we need to differ the classes by various position, the model will still "learn" through tuning the weights accordingly. It seems that my old understanding on CNN is biased and thank you again by clarifying that !

Comment: *the downsampling part tries to extract high-level features while "ignoring" the spatial information*. The role of downsampling layer is solely reducing the feature dimension for to have less computation. It is rather a *dumb* layer. While it might seem it reduces the *spatial* information in early layers, what it does is actually dropping features outputted from previous layer based on some criteria to make the job of next layer simpler. If we had unlimited resources for training CNNs, we could get rid of down/up sampling layers altogether.

Comment: The up-sampling layer is needed to restore the dimension of data. Otherwise, the dimension of data would collapse after a few down-sampling layers. *the model ignores on purpose the spatial information by tuning the weights properly*: Exactly. The CNN ignores the spatial information **because** we have ignored it our training dataset. Imagine training a CNN to detect person in image. One can train it to detect a person any person as `person`. Somebody else might train a more fine-grained CNN (e.g. `sitting person`, `bending person`, `bald person`, `crying person`, etc)...

Comment: ...The magic of CNN is that it **learns** what features it should consider and extract from the image to be able to distinguish these classes. If the position/orientation helps the classification, it preserve it. If it doesn't, it is eliminated. Likewise the other features (rotation, color, size, smoothness, etc). There are millions of features that we cannot even name them, but CNN can try learn and exploit them if they can be helpful in classification. I highly recommend [Stanford cs231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu) course on this topic. Watch their videos if you are interested.

Comment: Great explanation! I shall study Stanford cs231n more carefully. Thank you again. @Isaac